# Solution of a integral

Tags: integration

$$
\int e^x \, \left(1 + \frac{e^{-x}}{x} \right) \,dx
$$
I got three different integrals from this one, which are integral of $e^x$, integral of $1/x$ and the third one is integral of $e^{-x}/x$ but I'm not sure how to solve the third one? Thanks in advnace.

Comment: How you got the third integral?

Comment: @Voliar well, I made 1 to 1/x and the other part stays as it is, so I just splitted it to two integrals? Is it wrong?

Comment: @user133022: You can't split over multiplication, just over sum (algebraic sum, which include subtraction as well). See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint**: After distributing multiplication, use the fact that:
$$\displaystyle\int \left [ kf(x) + hg(x) \right ] dx = k\int f(x) dx + h\int g(x) dx$$

Complete spoiler (mouseover to reveal):

> $$\displaystyle\int e^x \left ( 1 + \dfrac{e^{-x}}{x} \right ) dx = \int \left ( e^x + \dfrac{e^x \cdot e^{-x}}{x} \right ) dx = \int e^x dx + \int \dfrac{1}{x} dx = e^x + \ln |x| + C$$

Answer (score 8):

It should come out as  $ \int (e^x + \frac{1}{x} ) \,dx $ since the powers cancel out.

Comment: Everybody is writing so beautifully, and my writing is so ugly. I should learn LaTeX or something... I am just viewing the source on different posts and copying it.

Comment: As far as I know, it always comes down to adding `\displaystyle`. It changes everything. Also use `\left (` and `\right )` for adapting parentheses (they automatically become big).

Comment: Thanks, the mouseover thing you did was awesome!

Comment: Oh thank you! Of course I learned it from some other guy here on Math.SE!

Comment: Use two dollar signs instead of one if you want it to be centered and large.

Answer (score 5):

$$\int e^x \bigg(1+ \frac{e^{-x}}{x} \bigg) dx = \int e^x + \frac{1}{x} dx = \int e^xdx + \int \frac{1}{x} dx $$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 4):

Simplify first; integrate afterwards:
$$
e^x\left( 1+ \frac{e^{-x}}{x} \right) = e^x + \frac 1 x.
$$

Answer (score 4):

We have$$\int e^x\left(1+\frac{e^{-x}}{x}\right)dx=\int \left(e^x+\frac{e^{x}e^{-x}}{x}\right)dx=\int e^xdx +\int\frac{1}{x}dx$$

I suppose you can do the rest..

Comment: Why has this answer been downvoted?

Comment: @rubik Good question. I'm curious too - perhaps I shouldn't have given the answer straight. By the way, great answer, especially the mouseover. +1

Comment: I downvoted for using $\ln|x|$ without mentioning that $0$ splits it into 2 primitive functions. But it's now removed, so I retract it.

Comment: @user2345215: Thanks for explaining the reason for your downvote.